# What does this code do?

Tags: controllers, search

I am currently looking in to how my search works on my website and can't understand this function...

```
   public function getFrontController()
{
    if (!$this->_frontController) {
        $this->_initFrontController();
    }

    return $this->_frontController;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there isn't a fontController active then it inits a new frontController.